# PHP - Proper order of adding - ob_start(), session_start(), setcookie(), header.php(including DB)?

Tags: php

I am creating a small application, and I have been searching for a solid answer of, what is the order that is correct to add, **session_start(), ob_start(), setcookie(), or database**. People debate on that. Can someone tell me the right way of ordering those?

Thanks.

Comment: `session_start()` and `setcookie()` are not dependent to each other and `ob_start()` must come ahead `session_start()`

Comment: ob_start() is often use to get around poorly structured code, dont use it for that.

Comment: @nogad I think `ob_start()` is used for either terrible or great code.

Comment: @pro78 not related to this question, I wanted to mention since your last question regarding editors was deleted. Visual Studio Code is not the same thing as Visual Studio. It's a general code editor with git access built in and supports numerous languages for syntax. Try it out.